# Field is present in output, but getting KeyError

Tags: python, pandas

Below is my output. As you can see, children is clearly a (dictionary) field in my response.

[image: Output result]

This code works perfectly, but it keeps any nested fields (lists or dictionaries) as is:

```
user = "" 
password = getattr(config, 'password') 
url = ''
req = requests.post(url = url, auth=(user, password))
print('Authentication succesful!/n')
ans = req.json()

#Transform resultList into Pandas DF
solr_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(ans['resultList']), orient='columns')
```

I instead would like to normalize the `"children"` field, so I did the following instead of the last row above:

```
solr_df = pd.DataFrame()
for record in ans['resultList']:
    df = pd.DataFrame(record['children']) 
    df['contactId'] = record['contactId']
    solr_df = solr_df.append(df)
```

However, I am getting a `KeyError: 'children'`.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like there are a lot of entries in that `resultList`. Are you sure _all_ of them have a `children` key?

Comment: @glibdud yes, but I am assuming there are REALLY rare cases where the dict will be empty

Comment: as @glibdud said, if even one record lacks a 'children' key you'll get that error. Wrap in a `try/except` or  check for a key with `'children' in record.keys()` and you'll find out if you're missing one.

Comment: @MCBama the assumption here is that I know what Im doing but unfortunately I am pretty new to Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the message is `KeyError: 'children'`, the only plausible reason for the error is that the children key is missing in one of the dicts. You can avoid the exception by using a try/except block, or can pass in a default value for the key, like:

```
solr_df = pd.DataFrame()
for record in ans['resultList']:
    df = pd.DataFrame(record.get('children', {}) 
    df['contactId'] = record.get('contactId')
    solr_df = solr_df.append(df)
```

Comment: Question, why does `df = pd.DataFrame(record.get('children', {}))` work, but `df = pd.DataFrame(record['children'],{})` gives ValueError: Shape of passed values is (18, 2), indices imply (18, 0)? What does `get` do exactly that make it work that it makes it work here

Comment: @user8834780 `record.get('children', {})` is a python dictionary function that checks to see if the key exists on the record and pulls that key but if the key doesn't exist it makes it and provides a default value. Prevents KeyErrors by ensuring you at least get a default value.

Comment: Magical. Thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

One of your records is probably missing the 'children' key so catch that exception and continue processing the rest of the output.

```
solr_df = pd.DataFrame()
for record in ans['resultList']:
  try:
    df = pd.DataFrame(record['children']) 
    df['contactId'] = record['contactId']
    solr_df = solr_df.append(df)
  except KeyError as e:
    print("Record {} triggered {}".format(record, e))
```

Comment: Thanks, there were 3 out of 10s of thousands haha

Comment: Yeah figured it had to be something like that. Glad your problem was fixed :)